# nginx location block capturing a value and setting cookie if it's not empty, redirect to new URL

Tags: regex, url, nginx, location, match

Hard to summarize in title...
I'm trying to create a URL that will save a specified value to a cookie, and then redirect the user in order to get rid of the value in the URL.

Desires:

domain.com/importantpage => Redirect to importantpage.php (dont modify cookie!)

domain.com/importantpage/ => Redirect to importantpage.php (dont modify cookie!) **This one isn't important, but it would be nice**

domain.com/importantpage/aSECRETvalue33 => set secret_code cookie to aSECRETvalue33 and Redirect to importantpage.php

What I currently wrote up:

```
location ~ ^/importantpage/?(.*?)$ {
    add_header Set-Cookie "secret_code=$1;Domain=$server_name;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HTTPOnly" always;
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}
```

This isn't good enough because domain.com/importantpage (with or without slash) is setting the cookie to a BLANK value. I want users to be able to navigate to domain.com/importantpage and have it read the existing cookie, if it's been provided.

I thought about breaking it out in two locations like so:

```
location ~ ^/importantpage$ {
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}

location ~ ^/importantpage/(.*?)$ {
    add_header Set-Cookie "secret_code=$1;Domain=$server_name;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HTTPOnly" always;
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}
```

But for some reason that I'm not sure of... it doesn't work how I imagine. In theory, the top one should only be called by domain.com/importantpage and avoid setting the cookie.. but if a / is provided (with or without a value), the second one should get called... but instead when I navigate to domain.com/importantpage it's STILL setting a cookie with a blank value?? Even though the second one REQUIRES a trailing slash to match to it? Maybe something non-obvious is going on behind the scenes.

Anyone have any ideas? Perhaps there's a way to force regex to match to 1 or more non-whitespace characters, or an IF statement to only call setcookie if the value isn't blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the single-block snippet, `^/importantpage/?(.*?)$` matches `/importantpage` followed by zero or one slashes followed by zero or more characters followed by the end of the input, so [it matches `/importantpage/aSECRETvalue33`, `/importantpage`, and `/importantpageisnothere/some/other/path`](https://regex101.com/r/CufCFU/2). Note that `.*?` is like `.*` (zero or more of any character) but matches non-greedily, which is unnecessary in this case since the only character you’ve allowed to follow it is the end of the input anyway.

In the double-block snippet, since both are non-exact prefixes, [nginx looks for the **longest** match](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms). You can instead separate your blocks into exact matches and a prefix match:

```
location = /importantpage {
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}

location = /importantpage/ {
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}

location ~ ^/importantpage/(.+)$ {
    add_header Set-Cookie "secret_code=$1;Domain=$server_name;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HTTPOnly" always;
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}
```

Or you can only deal with the second case by fixing your regex to only match when there are characters following the `/`:

```
location ~ ^/importantpage/(.+)$ {
    add_header Set-Cookie "secret_code=$1;Domain=$server_name;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HTTPOnly" always;
    return 307 $scheme://$server_name/importantpage.php;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great, but more importantly thank you for the great, detailed explanation.